# MySQL Query is overwriting elements in array

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

My SQL-Query is overwriting elements with the same name. But the names a coming from different tables and have different name, e.g. [articles][name], [companies][name].

I have these tables.

1.) Shop_Articles_Category_Allocation
2.) Portfolio
3.) Articles
4.) Companies
5.) Category

Example:

```
Shop_Category_Articles_Allocation
   id      | portfolio_id  | article_id
   Primary   To Protfolio    Articles

Portfolio
id | company_id | ....
     To Company

Company
id | name | ...

Articles
id | name | ...
```

And my Code:

```
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $sql =  " 
            SELECT *
            FROM shop_cat_art_alloc scaa 
            INNER JOIN portfolio p ON scaa.article_id = p.article_id
            INNER JOIN companies c ON p.company_id = c.id
            INNER JOIN articles a ON scaa.article_id = a.id


            WHERE scaa.shop_cat_id IN ($cat_id )
            AND a.state_id = (:state_id)
            AND p.state_id = (:state_id)
            AND scaa.state_id = (:state_id)
            AND c.state_id = (:state_id)
        ";

        $stmt = $em->getConnection()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindParam(':state_id', $state_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result_articles = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Now I get a result that is positive but in this case the name of the company is overwritten in the array. I get an array like this:

```
[id] => 1 [article_id] => 1 [name] => Chucks //this is the article name but there is no company name anymore.
```

How can I make the query that I can get to the company name too and still be able to get to the article name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aliases, substitute the wild card `*` and name your columns and give ones that collide aliases.

```
select user.name as username, account.name as accountname 
from table
```

More info on Aliases :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/identifiers.html